# Why does a ring homomorphism induce a continuous map between spectra?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let $\varphi: A \rightarrow B$   be a ring homomorphism. Let $f =\mathrm{Spec}(\varphi) : \mathrm{Spec}(B) \to \mathrm{Spec}(A)$ be the map associated to $\varphi$.

Why is the map $f$ is continuous?

I think we need to use $IB$ (the ideal of $B$ generated by $\varphi(I)$).

Then we got $f^{-1}(V(I)) = V(IB)$. (why?)

Could someone tell the details of this proof? Thank you :)

Comment: Thank you, can you help to proof this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, $f^{-1}(V(I))=V(\phi(I) B)$ is true, and this is straight forward to prove (you should try it).

Alternatively, it suffices to prove that $f^{-1}(D(a))=D(\phi(a))$, and this is because

$$\mathfrak{p} \in f^{-1}(D(a)) \Leftrightarrow a \notin f(\mathfrak{p})  = \phi^{-1}(\mathfrak{p}) \Leftrightarrow \phi(a) \notin \mathfrak{p}  \Leftrightarrow \mathfrak{p} \in D(\phi(a)).$$

Comment: Thank you very much, does it means we get p∈f −1 (D(a)) and p∈D(ϕ(a)). since here is f −1 (D(a))=D(ϕ(a)) , so $f$ is continuous?

Comment: I don't understand what you ask. If you are unsure why proving $f^{-1}(D(a))=D(\phi(a))$ is enough, you should recall the definitions (topology, topology on the spectrum, the notion of a basis, continuity of maps).